# How to find where a custom event listener has been added?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

There is a 3rd party piece of code running in a "friendly" iframe on a page. The code may or may not have added a listener for one of it's own custom events to any element on the outer page, or in one of the iframes somewhere on the page (either on their window, document or dom elements).

I know the name of the custom event, but how can I tell where the listener has been added?

Comment: Check out iframe sandboxing http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: Why do you need to know _where_ it's added?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible from javascript alone, but you can Chrome dev tools. Inspect the element you suspect there's an event listener attached to and find the 'Event Listeners' tab right next to the 'Styles' tab.

Comment: @Halcyon I want to also add a listener for that same event, so in my code I can do something when that event is fired.

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff Thanks but I was trying to avoid going through all of the hundreds of elements that way. The dom is also changing as I work so can't be sure if I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option - override the standard implementation:

```js
var addEventListenerImplementation = Node.prototype.addEventListener;

Node.prototype.addEventListener = function (event, callback) {
    alert("Hey, someone attached an event handler to me");
    addEventListenerImplementation.call(this, event, callback);
};

document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
div {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"/>
```

This should work in most cases but unfortunately `addEventListener` isn't the only way to attach events so you might need to also override `Event.prototype.observe`. Lastly, if the event handler is attached using `element.onclick` or any other `onevent` function you can't really override them. One possible though super-messy solution would be the following:

1. Define a new property on `Node.prototype`.

   `Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, "ONMYCLICK", function () {
       get: function () { return null; },
       set: function (handler) { 
            console.log("Hey, a handler was attached!");
            this.onclick = handler;
       }
   });`
2. Open the library's script in your favourite text editor and replace all occurences of `.onclick` with `.ONMYCLICK`
3. ???
4. Profit